# Refused to display a website in a frame because of its 'X-Frame-Options'

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, x-frame-options

I'm trying to display Facebook page in an simple HTML page which only contains an iframe.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm always getting this error in Google Chrome's console:

> Refused to display 'http://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

BTW, I'm having this problem also with these iframes:

```
<iframe src="https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/any"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://m.facebook.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://m.youtube.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://m.dropbox.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://m.yahoo.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://mail.google.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.dropbox.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
```

Meanwhile, this iframe is working well !

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom"></iframe>
```

**How to solve this ?**

*EDIT based on comments:* 
 Is there an alternative of using iframe if this is unsolvable ? Something like [`browser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser) tag in [`XUL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL) ? I already tried browser tag in Firefox extension and it works well, but I'm now coding a chrome extension, so I cannot depend on XUL anymore ?

Comment: You can't solve this. They're blocking their content fro being loaded in frames which is what you're doing.

Comment: That's because "Refused to display 'http://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'." In other words, Facebook set X-Frame-Options to DENY, to stop you from putting them in an iFrame.

Comment: Is there an alternative of using iframe ? something like "browser tag" in XUL ? I already tried browser tag in Firefox extension and it works well, but I'm now writing chrome extension, so I cannot depend on XUL anymore

Comment: This is why Facebook, Twitter and many other services expose their API through SDK's. They don't want you loading their content in an iFrame. If you are going to load it, it has to be through the proper channels. See [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com)

Comment: You should propably rephrase this question and ask it again with tags related to chrome and plugin dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who are interested, this cannot be done !

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you could

- use server-side includes, to fetch it from the server and include it in an iframe
- use a custom browser which does not recognize that header
- complicated: use websockets to create your own Javascript HTTP client, fetch the page, and insert it into the DOM